# Need help Spark SQL or SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, join, group-by, self

I need help to get the desired results in SQL or Spark. My input is below
Input Table

```
Key   Rate  Invoice Date
Key1    10  1/1/2017
key1    10  1/5/2017
key1    20  1/20/2017
key1    10  1/25/2017
Key2    30  2/1/2017
```

My desired output is below:

```
Key   Rate  start_date  end_date
key1    10  1/1/2017    1/5/2017
key1    20  1/20/2017   1/20/2017
key1    10  1/25/2017   1/25/2017
key2    30  2/1/2017    2/1/2017
```

Comment: What did you try?  What was your result or error?  Show us some code!

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky.  It is called a gap-and-islands problem and one way to solve it uses the difference of row numbers:

```
select key, rate, min(invoice_date), max(invoice_date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by invoice_date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by key, rate order by invoice_date) as seqnum_kr,
      from t
     ) t
group by key, rate, (seqnum - seqnum_kr);
```

To understand how this works, run the subquery and you'll see how the difference in row numbers defines each group.